# Post json data with PHPCuRL Raw data

Tags: php, json

```
$data = array('msisdn' =>'01033000939','basic'=>true);
        $data_json = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->urlFullSubs);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));
        $response  = curl_exec($ch);
        $s = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
```

Hi I want to get information from the API and i POST Json data using PHP Curl but I cannot get the output.Can someone let me know where did I do wrong

Comment: do you receive any errors?

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin got no error but the output only get string(0) ""

Comment: have you tried ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);```? it could show errors to stderr or log file. more info https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html

Comment: have you tried same curl request from console via curl command (without using php)?